# How to forcing a unique rule to ignore a given id?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

While updating the "users" table, I want the EditUserRequest form checkout to ignore the current email because it already exists.
Code rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required|max:200',
        'email' =>  [
                        'required',
                        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
                    ],
        'pass1' => 'required|min:6',
        'pass2' => 'same:pass1',
    ];
}
```

Code UserController:

```
public function postEdit($id,EditUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->username;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->pass1);
    $user->level = $request->get('cbadmin',0);
    $user->save();
    return view('admin.edit-user')->with('success','Sửa thành công!');
}
```

This line: `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email'` will check email exists. However, the default email I need to update it already exists. Did I read:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique. But I do not understand how to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Field UNIQUE (already taken) in edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829840/field-unique-already-taken-in-edit)

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: please post how you do your validation .. there are different types ..

Answer (score 2):

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|max:200',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.request()->user()->id,
            'pass1' => 'required|min:6',
            'pass2' => 'same:pass1',
        ];
    }
```

You can pass a third parameter as id to ignore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have modified the code above. But it still fails. You review your help with

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of your route parameter names since your routes aren't included in the post, so I will assume `$id` on the controller method means there is a route parameter named `id`.

```
'email' =>  [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('id')),
],
```

This would use the `id` from the route parameter, assuming it was named `id`. This will tell the rule to ignore the unique check on this email field for this particular User id.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using the Rule facade ..

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
```

**EDIT**

in case you're using a function to validate your inputs you may do it like this:

```
protected function yourValidatorName(array $data, $id)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username' => 'required|max:200',
        'email' =>  [
            'required',
             Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id),
        ],
        'pass1' => 'required|min:6',
        'pass2' => 'same:pass1',
    ]);
}
```

then

```
public function postEdit($id, EditUserRequest $request)
{
    $accountValidate = $this->yourValidatorName($request->all(), $id);
    if (!$accountValidate->fails())
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // failed
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code above. But it still fails. You review your help with

Comment: form requests get validated when resolved from the container. the validator is created and validated before you even get to the first line of that method, `postEdit`.

Comment: request got to the `postEdit` gets validated before saving if success ..

Answer (score 1):

Can you show me your route for `postEdit`?

For example this is your route:

```
Route::put('users/{user_id_sample}', 'UserController@postEdit');
```

You may do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required|max:200',
        'email' =>  [
                        'required',
                        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('user_id_sample')),
                    ],
        'pass1' => 'required|min:6',
        'pass2' => 'same:pass1',
    ];
}
```